# How to add CheckBox Column in DataGrid Control?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagrid

I have tried to add a `CheckBox` to a `DataGrid` (.Net 2.0, Not the DataGridView), but isn't working. What am I doing wrong?
My attempt:

```
DataColumn colNewDGCol = new DataColumn();
colNewDGCol.DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean");
colNewDGCol.DefaultValue = false;
colNewDGCol.ColumnName = ("ck");
ds.Columns.Add(colNewDGCol);
```

Comment: While you can use `typeof(bool)` instead of `System.Type.GetType("System.Boolean")` but there is no problem in your code. What't the problem. Do you receive any error?

Comment: no errors here, but cells of this column show text: "false" not checkbox

Comment: Maybe you set some table style for your grid?

Comment: DataGridTableStyle tableStyle = new DataGridTableStyle();
MyGrid.TableStyles.Add(tableStyle);

i add this, but i don't think it's problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set the cell template of the column you wish to become checkbox column.

```
DataGridViewColumn col1 = new DataGridViewColumn();
DataGridViewCell cell = new DataGridViewCheckBoxCell();
col1.CellTemplate = cell;
```